# Spark - Capping the number of CPU cores or memory of slave servers

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.1. This question is for use cases where some of Spark slave servers run other apps as well.  Is there a way to tell the Spark Master server to to use only certain # of CPU cores or memory of a slave server ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of cores used by a spark job, you need to add the `--total-executor-cores` option into your spark-submit command. To limit the amount of memory used by each executor, use the `--executor-memory` option. For example:

```
spark-submit --total-executor-cores 10 \
             --executor-memory 8g \
             --class com.example.SparkJob \
             SparkJob.jar
```

This also works with spark-shell

```
spark-shell --total-executor-cores 10 \
             --executor-memory 8g
```

Comment: Thanks Steven for your  response. However, it involves the settings per job level. My question was at the slave server level, so that the master server would use only a subset of CPU cores and/or memory of a particular slave server. Here are more details of this use case.

1. 2 slave servers with 16 cores each.

2. all 16 cores on slave server #1 can be used

3. slave server #2 also runs another program, so I want the master server to use at most 8 CPU cores out of 16 total.

4. There are multiple jobs running concurrently, so you don't want to constrain per job.

Comment: @Steven, I use spark submit as you mention, 
spark2-submit --class org.apache.spark.SparkProgram.requestapp --master yarn  --deploy-mode cluster --total-executor-cores 10 --executor-memory 8g  /aaa/requestapp_2.11-1.0.jar

However when I submitted job, it used 17 Vcores and 17 Container. Actually it should use 10 vcores .
How can I restrict it